Instance of decorated class not working with instanceof
I have class decorator which ensures that the class remains a singleton.
interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function Singleton() {
    let instance: Object;
    return function <SingletonFunction extends Type>(
        constructor: SingletonFunction
    ) {
        return <SingletonFunction>class {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                if (instance) {
                    return instance;
                } else {
                    instance = new constructor(...args);
                    Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, constructor);
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        };
    };
}


When I use this decorator on a class like this,
@Singleton()
class TestSingleton {
    private field: any;
    private field2 = Math.random();

    constructor(args: any[]) {
        this.field = args.reduce((acc, ele) => {
            return acc + ele;
        }, 0);
    }
}

const x = new TestSingleton([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
const y = new TestSingleton([6, 7, 8, 9, 1]);

console.log(x === y); // true
console.log(x instanceof TestSingleton); // false

The instanceof operator does not work, I can not figure out what I am missing here.

@jcalz yeah my bad, fixed them

Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, constructor); is totally weird. Don't do that, it breaks instanceof (and other things)! What were you trying to achieve with this?!

The singleton pattern is inappropriate for constructors taking options anyway.

@Bergi Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, constructor); this was me trying something. And I can remove constructor arguments, I just put them there for testing.

Remove the setPrototypeOf call and it should work.

@Bergi I added setPrototypeOf call because it was not working, just trying something. The test for instanceof check is failing

You need the new class to be somewhere in the inheritance chain for the decorated constructor. By far the easiest thing is to subclass the decorated constructor like in this playground link. Anything else is a nightmare since you'd be modifying an existing prototype chain. Where should you insert the new thing? At the top? The middle somewhere? You could do something like this playground link shows but I wouldn't want to deal with awful edge cases. Does that fully address the question? If so I could maybe write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Ignoring the attempt to Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, constructor), the problem is with instance = new constructor(...args);. This calls the old (wrapped, decorated) constructor, which returns an object inheriting from the old .prototype. However your decorator completely replaces the TestSingleton class (which it must, to overwrite the constructor), and instanceof TestSingleton will therefor check inheritance against the new (returned) TestSingleton.prototype object.
The conventional approach is to just return a class that inherits from the original (decorated) class, and have the constructor return instances of the subclass (as it creates them by default, if you didn't have your singleton instance code overriding the constructor return value).
However, this creates an unnecessary extra prototype object and unnecessary extra prototype chain link. I would rather recommend to return a class (or simple function) that has exactly the same prototype as the decorated one:
function Singleton<Args extends any[], Res extends object>(
    constructor: { new (...args: Args): Res }
) {
    let instance: Res;
    function newConstructor(...args: Args) {
        if (new.target != newConstructor) throw new Error('not supported');
        if (instance) {
            return instance;
        } else {
            instance = new constructor(...args);
            return instance;
        }
    };
    newConstructor.prototype = constructor.prototype;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    newConstructor.prototype.constructor = newConstructor; // properly hide the decorated original constructor
    return newConstructor as unknown as { new (...args: Args): Res };
}

@Singleton
class TestSingleton {
    …
}

